# Дойдет ли до клиента ошибка, не обработанная в WHEN other THEN?

Tags: oracle, исключения, plsql

Есть такой код:

```
SELECT TABLE_ID
    INTO ID
    FROM TABLE;

    raise_application_error (-20202, 'Error');

EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        IF SQLCODE = '-20202' THEN
            raise DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
        END IF;
```

Если в Select не произойдет ошибки, я вызову ошибку со своим кодом, поймаю ее и в итоге отдам DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX (которая будет содержать и DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX и мою кастомную ошибку). Этого я и добивался, оборачивая стандартной ошибкой мою.

Но если Select выдаст ошибку. То мы не сгененрируем свою, не попадем в IF, то до клиента дойдет ошибка, которая произошла в Select?

Comment: По-моему, быстрее попробовать... всё одно, узнав "как", будешь спрашивать "почему".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но если Select выдаст ошибку. То мы не сгененрируем свою, не попадем в IF, то до клиента дойдет ошибка, которая произошла в Select?

Нет, она будет проглочена.

Если `raise` не вызывается, то блок равносилен следующему:

```
exception
    when others then
        null;
```

Чтобы выбросить пойманное исключение используйте [`RAISE` без аргументов](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960):

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        IF SQLCODE = '-20101' THEN
            raise DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
        END IF;
        RAISE; -- другие исключения
```

P.S. В примере почему-то при выбрасывании код -20102, а при обработке -20101

Comment: Т.е. если RAISE без аргументов в обработчике EXCEPTION, то выдаст исходную ошибку?

Comment: @ks_on_v да, посмотрите в примере по ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Небольшое замечание. Блок `WHEN .. THEN ...` в обработчике ошибок предназначен как раз для сортировки типов ошибок (то есть для того, что вы делаете в `IF ... THEN ...`), так что идеологически более правильно в вашем коде написать как-то так:

```
declare
  my_custom_error exception;    -- объявляем свой эксепшен
  pragma exception_init(my_custom_error, -20202);  -- привязываем его к коду -20202
begin
  SELECT TABLE_ID
    INTO ID
    FROM TABLE;

    raise_application_error (-20202, 'Error');

EXCEPTION
  when my_custom_error then
    raise DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
  WHEN others THEN
    raise;
end;
```